# How to update an item in database with SQLite in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I am trying to update the user infos on my app.

I can add a user in my database but when I am trying to update its information, it is not working.

Here is the function that change information:

```
 public void ChangerLanguageValue(string language)
 {
     var myuser = userinfodatabase.GetUsers();
     myuser.NewsLanguage = language;     
     userinfodatabase.UpdateUserInfos(myuser); // this does not work
 }
```

Here is my database configuration :

```
class UserInfosDatabase
{
    private SQLiteConnection conn;

    public UserInfosDatabase()
    {
        conn = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
        conn.CreateTable<MyUser>();
    }

    public string AddUser(MyUser localuser)
    {
        conn.Insert(localuser);
        return "success";
    }

    public MyUser GetUsers()
    {
        var users = (from u in conn.Table<MyUser>() select u);
        return users.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
    }

    //Update
    public string UpdateUserInfos(MyUser localuser)
    {
        conn.Update(localuser);
        return "succes";
    }

}
```

Comment: You could  change the method as a task `public Task <string>UpdateUserInfos(MyUser localuser)
    {
        conn.UpdateAsync(localuser);
        return "success";
    }`

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT  I do not have UpdateAsynch

Comment: Check https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

Comment: I will post it as answer , could you accept it ?Which will help more people :)

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Yes of course with pleasure !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQLite in Xamarin.Forms we could use the plugin  [sqlite-net-pcl](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) .

It has very simple methods for executing CRUD operations and queries safely (using parameters) and for retrieving the results of those query in a strongly typed fashion.

In your case , you would better update the data as `async`

```
public Task <string>UpdateUserInfos(MyUser localuser) 
{ 
   conn.UpdateAsync(localuser); 
   return "success"; 
}
```